# curve fitting in scipy is of poor quality. How can I improve it?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm doing a fit of a set results to a predicted function. The function might be interpreted as linear but I might have to change it a little so I am doing curve fitting instead of linear regression. I use the `curve_fit` function in `scipy`. Here is how I use it

```
 kappa = 1
        alpha=2
        popt,pcov = curve_fit(fitFunc1,self.X[0:3],self.Y[0:3],sigma=self.Err[0:3],p0=[kappa,alpha])
```

and here is `fitFunc1`

```
def fitFunc1(X,kappa,alpha):

    out = []
    for x in X:
        y = log(kappa)
        y += 4*log(pi)
        y += alpha*x 
        y -= 2*log(2)
        out.append(-y)
    return np.array(out)
```

Here is an example of the fit [image]. The green line is a matlab fit. The red one is a scipy fit. I carry the fist over the first three dots.

Comment: Were you expecting the same result from Matlab and scipy? What seems wrong about the scipy fit? What is your question?

Comment: scipy's fit seems better.

Comment: How are you performing the fit in matlab??

Comment: What's the sum-of-square error of `scipy` fit, of `matlab` fit? `matlab` fit clear show a problem that the residues are correlated with x (basically means the difference between `y` and `y_predict` is positively correlated with x). `scipy` fit appear to be free of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using non-linear fitting routines to fit the data, not linear least-squares as invoked by `A\b`. The result is that the matlab and/or scipy minimization routines are getting stuck in local minima during the optimizations, leading to different results.

You should get the same results (to within numerical precision) if you apply logs to the raw data prior to linear fitting with `A\b` (in matlab).

*edit*

Inspecting function `fitFunc1` it looks like the `x/y` data have already been transformed prior to the fit within scipy.

I performed a linear fit with the data shown, using matlab. The results using linear least squares with the operation `polyfit(x,y,1)` (essentially a linear fit) is very similar to the scipy result:

[image]

In any case, the data looks piecewise linear so a better solution *may* be to attempt a piecewise linear fit. On the other the log transformation can do all sorts of unwanted stuff, so performing nonlinear fits on the original data without performing a log tranform may be the best solution.

Comment: What do you mean by ``A/b``? Apart from that, I understand your point. I guess there is no simple way to overcome this. If I apply linear fitting, in matlab, how do I fit to the 0's order (only the free variable)?

Comment: @Yotam A\b refers to a linear least squares fit operation in matlab. You can do similar with polyfit. Please see my addition to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind having a little bit of extra work I suggest using [PyMinuit](https://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/) or [iMinuit](https://github.com/iminuit/iminuit), both are minimisation packages based on Seal Minuit.

Then you can minimise a Chi Sq function or maximise the likelihood of your data in relation to your fit function. They also provide all the errors and everything you would like to know about the fit.

Hope this helps! xD